# fetch not executing with correct params - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, isomorphic-fetch-api

So I have a React Native app, making calls to my own external api via the fetch() native API. I am encountering a strange issue with my requests not being processed by fetch() correctly in only one context.

The calls are *supposed* to POST to `/api/token_login`.

Here is how I make my calls in the app:

```
#/src/services/post.js

import headers from './headers';

const APIURL = '******/api';

export default async (path, data, callback) => {
  try {
    const postData = {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: new Headers(headers),
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    };
    const requestURL = `${APIURL}/${path}`;
    const request = new Request(requestURL, postData);
    const response = await fetch(request);
    const res = await response.text();
    if (response.ok) {
      callback(null, res);
    } else {
      const error = res;
      callback(error, null);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('caught error: ', error);
  }
};


#/src/services/auth.js
import post from './post';

export function TokenLogin(data, callback) {
  post('token_login', data, callback);
}
...other functions

#/src/containers/Login.js
const data = {
  user: {
    auth_token: token,
  },
};
return TokenLogin(data, (err, response) => {
  const res = JSON.parse(response);
... do stuff
};
```

This function gets called on componentDidMount under certain conditions, which is the expected behavior. However, every day or so it suddenly stops sending the request to the passed in path, and sends a GET to /api/login instead. Changing the path passed into the function changes the behavior back to the expected one (i.e., passing in `flurgl` sends a POST request to `.../api/flurgl` with the body passed in correctly. Here is some debugging info:

```
// the logs:
=> Request method: POST url: https://*****/api/token_auth

=> Response object:  
=> Response {type: "default", status: 404, ok: false, statusText: undefined, headers: Headers, …}
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {map: {…}}
ok: false
status: 404
statusText: undefined
type: "default"
url: "https://*******/api/login"
```

Comment: There is a `404` status code at the logs

Comment: there is no route defined for GET /api/login, so 404 is the expected response code. the error is not that.